# Rails 3, saving data without a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

How do I save information from my site  http://yocoro.com/public into my database ?
just by going to the page

PS: I'm using 2 gems geocoder and user-agent to optain this information.

```
//controller
class PublicController < ApplicationController  
  def index  
      @time = Time.now  
      @user_agent = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']  
  end  
end

//view
<%= request.ip %>
<%= request.location.city %>  
<%= request.location.country_code %>  
<%= @user_agent %>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to save?

Comment: You could use a hidden form submitted via AJAX to call an action in your controller which saves the info.

Comment: @Broisatse: Im trying to save ip, city,country, and the hash from user_agent.

Comment: @Beartech :how do I do that, would I need to set up an empty model?

Comment: This is a basic, elementary, part of using Rails. Read though the [Active Record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) section of the Ruby on Rails tutorial and you'll learn how.

Comment: Yes, if you want to store the data locally, you should create a model. It seems like you should probably just include google analytics and be done with it though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on input from @meager I was able to trim this way down.

Create a model and the appropriate table to go with it

```
rails generate model location ip:text city:text country:text user_agent:text
```

Then in your index action just put the info together and store it:

```
def index
  @ip = ip_param
  # Here is where you use the IP address and the geocoder gem to gather the 
  # info from the ip address. Then create the location object and save it.
  @location = Location.new
  @location.ip = @ip
  @location.city = city
  @location.country = country
  @location.user_agent = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
  @location.save
end
```

here is how I finally did it..
I try this before it didn't work but I finally understand why, my old code had 
"@location = location.new" the letter -l- was lower case and rails was giving me an error after I change to "@location = Location.new" bingo bango it worked!!!.

thank you so much to everyone.!!!

```
  @location = Location.new
  @location.ip = request.ip
  @location.city = request.location.city
  @location.country = request.location.country_code
  @location.user_agent = request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

  if @location.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Location save'
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Location did not save' 
  end
```

Comment: No reason to do this with an second AJAX request after the normal request has finished. It should be a `before_filter` that just runs during the normal request.

Comment: How do you pull the ip from the original request to `index`?

Comment: The same way you're doing it now? `request.remote_ip`? You're already getting it server-side, the issue is that you're then sending it back to the client, just so the client can make *another* HTTP request to a different action with its IP, which you don't even need, because that different action could *also* just check `request.remote_ip`. It's extremely over-wrought.

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize it was available immediately to the controller. Yes, far simpler. Will edit my post.

Comment: I fixed my capitalization error with `Location.new`. If this is how you did it would you consider accepting the answer?

Answer (score 0):

At its most basic, Rails will let you map individual HTTP paths to a specific method in a specific controller:

```
get '/record_ip' => 'public#index'
```

This will match any URL starting with `/record_ip`, and use the parameters in that request within the method `index` in `PublicController`.

Inside `index`, you can do whatever you want with the database by accessing it via your models (of course, you can also do whatever you want that can be done via Ruby on your system.) When you're done, you need to use `respond_to` and `render` to decide what output to generate. If you don't call `render` explicitly, Rails will search for a template corresponding to the controller and method names, which is probably not what you want:

```
def index
  // Do something to the database
  // Your query parameters sent via a GET requests will be in the params hash

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: {'status' => "success"} }
  end
end
```

Now you can issue an HTTP GET request like `http://yourserver.com/matchip?param1=val1`. Note that Rails doesn't require you to have models - you could in fact do all your db manipulation with a SQL library.

Of course, that's just the simplest aspect of Rails routing and responses. There's a big iceberg beneath that tip for you to explore. If that's all you're doing, maybe Rails is overkill for you? You could manipulate a db pretty simply with just a custom PHP script.

Comment: I'm doing a little more than that. I have part of the app built on rails already and I'm trying to create a simple analytics. like tumblr has on it's dashboard.

google analytics is way overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish here.